# how to: while True in a function python 3

Tags: python, function, while-loop

When I use this code everything is OK, but how to put it inside a function?

I can't get to break part when inside a function, always repeat message from the input.

```
while True:
    country = input("Enter country of which you want to check pictures HR, RS, RO:  ").upper()
    if country == str("HR"): break
    if country == str("RO"): break
    if country == str("RS"):
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter HR or RO or RS: " + "you wrote: " + country)
```

Comment: Put your function code here please.

Comment: this works just fine, you're not telling us something. also, change you may want to chnge the last 2 `if` to `elif`

Comment: @Nullman Or instead remove the final `else` to be consistent. It's a question of style.

Comment: what input did you try? how do you put it inside a function? Show that function and your input. 
Also you can test if a `str` is in list by writing `country in ['HR', 'RO', 'RS']`, which is clearer

Comment: @Booboo this is a small script so not really an issue, but logically speaking it tests every `if`, thats a performance hit (negligible here ofc)

Comment: @Nullman  No. The `break` statements prevent that from happening. Once `break` is executed, execution falls out of the `while` and the next `if` is never tested.

Comment: @Booboo you are correct, but i've assumed that the `break`s are a stand in for something else (i realize i shouldnt assume)

Answer (score 1):

Here Is the Solution:

```
def Function(cot):
    while True:
        country = cot
        if country == str("HR"): return print("HR")
        if country == str("RO"): return print("RO")
        if country == str("RS"):
            return print("RS")
        else:
            print("Please enter HR or RO or RS: " + "you wrote: " + country)
```

***Function Call***

```
Function(input("Enter country of which you want to check pictures HR, RS, RO:  ").upper())
```

Comment: Rohan, get None if I use this

Comment: @JeoBlast What you want to say?

Comment: When print function after input i get None instead HR , RO or RS

Answer (score 0):

This is a working combination for if statement, but else is repeatedly printed if wrong str typed

```
def test(cot):
    while True:
        country = cot
        if country in ['HR', 'RO', 'RS']:
             return country
        else:
            print("Please enter HR or RO or RS: " + "you wrote: " + country)


test1 = test(input("Enter country of which you want to check pictures HR, RS, RO:  ").upper())
```